# Unable to use \subfloat

Tags: floats

I am trying to put two figures in eps format side by side. I followed the example given in IEEE transaction template, but my latex throws this error. How can I put two figures side by side without wasting space / minimum acceptable space in between the two figures? Thank you

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \subfloat 
                     [Case I]\includegraphics [width=2.5in]{Fig1a.eps}\lab...
l.20 \label{fig_first_case}}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<argument> \subfloat 
                     [Case I]\includegraphics [width=2.5in]{Fig1b.eps}\lab...
l.20 \label{fig_first_case}}

End of file on the terminal!
```

HEre is how I have done.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage {extarrows}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centerline{\subfloat[Case I]\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{Fig1a.eps}%
\label{fig_first_case}}
\hfil
\subfloat[Case II]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{Fig1b.eps}%
\label{fig_second_case}}}
\caption{Simulation results}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure*} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need `graphics` if you already have `graphicx`

Comment: Nor `epsf` which has been deprecated for more than 20 years, and replaced with `graphicx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{extarrows}
%\usepackage{epsf}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[Case I    \label{fig_first_case}]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{Fig1a.eps}}
\hfil
\subfloat[Case II   \label{fig_second_case}]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{Fig1b.eps}}
%
\caption{Simulation results}
    \label{fig_sim}
\end{figure*}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

don't gives any error. Differences to your MWE:

- added package `subfig`
- removed package `graphics`
- commented packages `epstopdf`, `epsf`, `float` wich aren't relevant for this case
- `\centerline{...}` is replaced with `\centering`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! IS there a way to reduce the white space between the two figures?

Comment: @SKM, now the space around figures is equal distributed (depends from images width). If you like to have small space, than you repalce `\hfil` with desired space (for example defined with `\hspace{<desired width> }`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [subfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package which provides the `\subfloat` command. Did you 'just' copy and paste the code 'somewhere'?

Your error message says `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \subfloat` which literally means that the command is not known to your setup (because none of the packages you use define it).

Comment: I did not use subfig package, should I simply use \usepackage{subfig}? Also, can you please say how to eliminate a lot of white space between the figure caption and the figure. I tried using \vspace{-0.9em} \caption{Result}  \vspace{-1.0em} but, the white spaces did not go away

Comment: also correct syntax to use `\subfloat` in your case is `\subfloat[Case II]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{Fig1b}%
\label{fig_second_case}}` (see braces on the end and removed image extension). You can move label to inside of caption as: `\subfloat[Case II \label{fig_second_case}]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{Fig1b}}`

Comment: @Zarko: Should I write `\usepackage{subfig}`? This throws error saying unidentfied package detected

Comment: @SKM, of course. In preamble of your document had to be `\usepackage{subfig}` ...

Comment: @Zarko: Thank you for your comments. I did put the package in the preamble, and removed the extra brace that you pointed out. But I am now getting these problems - Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Comment: And error ! Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.29 \label{fig_first_case}}
                            
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.29 \label{fig_first_case}}
                            
End of file on the terminal!

Comment: @SKM, see my answer below (i can put it in comment, sorry)